# Convert NSString to NSData Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

NSData *_secretData = [strValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

I am trying to convert this in Xamarin iOS.. But I am not getting dataUsingEncoding options in Xamarin iOS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSData _secretData = strValue.Encode(NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
```

or

```
NSData _secretData = strValue.Encode(NSStringEncoding.UTF8, false);
```

re: [NSString.Encode(NSStringEncoding, Boolean) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsstring.encode#Foundation_NSString_Encode_Foundation_NSStringEncoding_System_Boolean_)

Answer (score 0):

I did not tested it but this might need you

```
   NSData _secretData= strValue.DataUsingEncoding (NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
```